# How does one properly load/reload UITableViewCells in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

For about a week I've been trying to figure out this predicament with table view cells not loading/reloading properly, and it seems to only be an issue in iOS 15. Running the same code in an iOS below 15, the cells are loaded perfectly. When I run the app in iOS 15, the cells sometimes overlap and are sometimes spaced far apart. I found some posts that suggested the way to properly reload cells in iOS 15 is to use reconfigureRowsAtIndexPaths instead of reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, so I tried that and the cells are loading with *less* problems, but still are sometimes spaced too far apart.

Here is the current state of my cellForRowAt:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    VLMileageSummaryComparisonViewController *vc = [[VLMileageSummaryComparisonViewController alloc] init];
        
    UITableViewCell *cellComparison = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld_%ld", indexPath.section, indexPath.row]];
    if (cellComparison == nil) {
        cellComparison = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld_%ld", indexPath.section, indexPath.row]];
    }

    [cellComparison.contentView vl_removeAllSubviews];
        
    [cellComparison.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    vc.chartData = [self getChartDataForIndexPath:indexPath];
    [vc.view vl_PinEdgesToSuperview];
        
    cell = cellComparison;
    
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundInterfaceSecondary;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundInterfaceSecondary;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    
    return cell;
}
```

And here is my willDisplayCell, where I do the reconfiguring/reloading of cells:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Change the loading state of the chart data structure
    // When the loading state of the chart changes, reload that cell
    VLSummaryComparisonChartData *chartData = [self getChartDataForIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (chartData) {
        if (chartData.loadingState == LoadingStateUnknown) {
            if (self.reportComparisonDataSource) {
                chartData.loadingState = LoadingStateLoading;
                [self.reportComparisonDataSource getComparisonReportChartData:chartData force:true completion:^(SummaryComparisonData data, VLError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (error) {
                        chartData.loadingState = LoadingStateError;
                    } else {
                        chartData.data = data;
                        chartData.loadingState = LoadingStateLoaded;
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
                            [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                                [tableView reconfigureRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
                            }];
                        } else {
                            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                        }
                    });
                }];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how the spacing between cells is sometimes off. I also recently added contrasing colors to the cells' subviews and can see that the yellow view's height is sometimes off, and that seems to be related to the distance between cells being off:

[image]

Here is the nib for the VLMileageSummaryComparisonViewController with the yellow portion selected:

[image]

Would love and greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!!

Comment: Unrelated but `beginUpdates/endUpdates` and also `performBatchUpdates` have no effect for a single operation. The APIs are for **multiple** simultaneous insert/delete/move operations.

Comment: @vadian Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Went ahead and got rid of those

Comment: It looks like you are adding **another** `VLMileageSummaryComparisonViewController` view every time `cellForRowAt` is called -- but that should have been problematic before iOS 15. You're looking at this and thinking "cell spacing" -- but more likely, it's the cell height. Use `Debug View Hierarchy` and/or give your cell's subviews contrasting background colors so you (we) can see how the frames are really being laid-out.

Comment: @DonMag I updated the cellForRowAt so that the cell's contentView's subviews are being removed each time before adding another VLMileageSummaryComparisonViewController and that got rid of the overlapping issue I was seeing! Thank you! I'm still dealing with the spacing issue and added the contrasting colors like you suggested and reuploaded the image. I can see that for some reason the yellow view's height is not being calculated properly...

Comment: @michaelthedeveloper - tough to tell without knowing what all is going on, but it seems rather odd to be calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` from `willDisplayCell`. Is the **Height** of the yellow view dependent on the data?

Answer (score 0):

Creating instance of VLMileageSummaryComparisonViewController inside  tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath might be the reason for this issue.
Looks like you are fetching dome data from server in tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDidplayCell method that also might be the cause of the issue.
Try to restructure your code, restructuring can help you fix the issue.

Comment: I moved the creating of the VLMileageSummaryComparisonViewController out to its own function and did the fetching of the data outside of willDisplayCell and inside viewDidAppear instead and the result was the same